# when i write UITableViewDataSource i see error

Tags: swift

This my problem with swift

> this error   type viewcontroller does not conform to protocol
>   UITableViewDataSource

why

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{


    @IBOutlet  var v: UITableView!

       @IBAction func add(sender: UIButton) {
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09y0j.png)

Answer (score 1):

The protocol `UITableViewDataSource` requires a few methods.

You can easily find out what's missing and fix it:

- Press <kbd>⌘B</kbd> to build the code.
- Press <kbd>⌘4</kbd> to show the issue navigator.
- Click on the disclosure triangle in front of the issue line.
- Implement the displayed required methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put `UITableViewDataSource` on your View Controller without adding the protocol's required functions: `cellForRowAt`, `numberOfSections`, and `numberOfRowsInSection` (Swift 3 versions). Please read the following article to learn how to implement a basic `UITableView`:
https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two methods:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return anInteger
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this template for a UITableView and then add the extra functionality in.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
}
```